# Tea steeping as a function of infuser

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

Suppose I have two identical cups, but one has a spherical steel tea infuser and the other has a muslin, both with the same amount of tea. I add boiling water to both. Assume both the infuser and the muslin float without rotating.

If I say that the tea is ready after a specific "tea concentration" is reached, which cup will be ready first?

This is not from a homework or anything, I'm just curious about the effect the steeping tool has (if any).

Answer (score 1):

The key issue is how much the infuser and muslin block the diffusion of the tea contents. Random walking molecules will not get through the metal or cloth fibres, so the probability that a molecule crosses would be equal to the area of the holes divided by the total area of the strainer. The bigger the hole area, the less hindrance of diffusion.

Now, the relative hole sizes will vary a lot with model. Some metal infusers have thin and translucent meshes, others are mostly metal. My impression of muslin bags is that they have a finer mesh and are not as translucent, so I think they typically would be slower. But this obviously can vary.

Comment: I see. But wouldn't the effect of having less holes area be greater than the one given by the ratio since the water is cooling down?

Comment: How do you think the water cooling affects the spread?